Is the second law of thermodynamics about microstates or macrostates?
The second law of thermodynamics says that entropy is increasing. Since the entropy of a given macrostate depends entirely on the probability distribution of the microstates this appears to be a statement about microstates and the probability distribution they follow. In other words, the second law of thermodynamics says that that the microstates will follow a probability distribution that is as uniform as possible so that the entropy is maximized.
On the other hand, some sources word the second law of thermodynamics in terms of macrostates. An example is the book An Introduction to Thermal Physics by Schroeder where he says:

Any large system in equilibrium will be found in the macrostate with the greatest multiplicity (aside from fluctuations that are normally too small to measure).

Statements like these seem to take the probability distribution as fixed so that the second law is more about the multiplicity/probability of macrostates.
I think the two can be put together to summarize the second law as saying a system evolves towards a macrostate with the greatest entropy given that the microstates follow a probability distribution that is as uniform as possible.
Which viewpoint is more fundamental?

Micro and macro states come from statistical mechanics. The laws of thermodynamics predate the statistical mechanics approach.

@JonCuster I had always thought of statistical mechanics as more fundamental so shouldn't the laws of thermodynamics be expressed using it?

And yet the laws of thermodynamics do not require a specific model to still be applicable.

I cannot help but again point out to Jaynes' work... there is a website with many of his papers...if you search for it, you will find it for sure...

@TobiasFünke It seems I should read Jaynes' work right away.

yes. I mean you will also find other good authors, also for information theory-stat.mech.. But if you want to understand stat. mech. in relation to information theory, Jaynes is a good if not the best starting place.

The answer is that the second law has to do with both microstates and macrostates in different ways, but your formulation of the second law is missing a crucial qualifier that clears this whole thing up a lot. Namely, the second law can be better framed as requiring the differential of the entropy $S$ for an isolated system to obey,
\begin{gather*}
dS \geq 0
\end{gather*}
until the system reaches thermal equilibrium (at which point $dS = 0$). This means that, since the system is isolated, the macrostate the system winds up in at equilibrium will be the one with the highest entropy. For an isolated system (that thus has a fixed energy), the microcanonical ensemble from statistical mechanics can be used to describe the system along with the associated Boltzmann entropy formula,
\begin{gather*}
S_A = k_B \ln (\Omega_A )
\end{gather*}
where $\Omega_A$ is the multiplicity of microstates consistent with the macrostate labeled $A$. Thus, the entropy of an isolated system (like the universe, we postulate) will increase until reaching the state with the highest number of accessible microstates.
I want to mention a neat way of rationalizing the second law that I use with my students. If you consider your "isolated system" to be a set of dice, and the "macrostate" to be the roll that the whole collection of dice lands on, then the individual "microstates" are the enumerated rolls of each and every die in the collection. When you roll the dice, some rolls will happen far more often than others, especially as you increase the number of dice. If we just plot the relative standard deviation (RSD) of the overall dice roll from the mean using a Python code that simulates millions of dice rolls at a time, we get the empirical curve shown below. This shows that the RSD decreases as $n^{-0.5}$ where $n$ is the number of dice. If we imagine going towards the limit that $n\rightarrow \infty$ we will see the RSD slowly vanish. Namely, it becomes incredibly unlikely that we will roll a value that is relatively far away from the mean! This is because the number of ways to get a particular roll becomes more and more aggressively peaked about the mean, which is another way of saying the entropy of the "macrostate" is getting much more centered around certain outcomes. Thus, if I start in a "non-equilibrium" state like having 5,000 dice all landing on a 1 and then re-roll, it is absurdly likely that on the next roll I will move towards a higher entropy state until I land extremely close to the mean. Note that this also suggests that the second law is not absolute, but just a very strong probabilistic limit of what we will actually observe if we have complicated systems with many degrees of freedom evolving randomly.

Note that this analysis does become more complicated when you no longer deal with isolated systems. For instance, the entropy for the canonical ensemble is the Gibbs-Shannon entropy rather than the Boltzmann entropy. And the canonical ensemble does not obey the restriction that $dS \geq 0$ due to the fact that the probability of the system being in states with different energies is given by the Boltzmann distribution rather than the equiprobable states of the microcanonical ensemble. In this case, we can instead use the Clausius inequality to find relationships between thermodynamic free energies like the Helmholtz free energy $F$ and the spontaneity of processes. I.e., a spontaneous process at fixed $T$ and $V$ doing no non-$PV$ work must obey,
\begin{gather*}
dF \leq 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{constant }T,V)
\end{gather*}

the really astonishing statistical result is not that the $rsd \approx 1/\sqrt{n}$ but that with probability 1 (that is essentially always) the $\rm{limsup}|\frac{\sum (\pm1)}{\sqrt{2n\log \log n}}|=1$, the so-called theorem of iterated logarithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm. This also gives you the fluctuations of that rsd almost surely.

I was not aware of that theorem, so thanks for the interesting read!

if you thought it was interesting then enjoy these few pages of proof from the Master Teacher https://archive.org/details/probabilitytheor0000reny/page/402/mode/2up (it needs the Borel-Cantelli lemma see p398, para 5; $D$ is dispersion = standard deviation, $D^2$ is variance and Greek letters denote rv-s, an old fashioned book...)

Unfortunately I can’t actually see that resource as it only gives a few pages as a preview.

archive.org is free to all, just sign up and then you can see a few million documents...

@MattHanson Thank you! Your answer suggests that the second law is really about macrostates and the fact that a system tends towards a macrostate that maximizes the entropy. But I don't see how this also captures the idea that the microstates follow a probability distribution that is as uniform as possible.

Sorry, missed that detail. If you start from a canonical ensemble whose characteristic entropy is the Gibbs entropy and plug in the probability $p_j = \frac{1}{\Omega}$ (a completely uniform probability) then you recover the Boltzmann entropy formula. Since I argued the Boltzmann entropy formula suggests the second law with my silly dice example, you have basically shown that a system with uniform distribution maximizes the entropy, which is characteristic of the microcanonical ensemble.
